# How can I get information about threads of process?

Tags: ubuntu, process, thread

Hi I wanted to get information about threads of process, so used /proc/stat command in terminal. But get "permission denied" error. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `/proc/stat` is not a command. What do you mean by threads of a process? The PIDs of the threads?

Answer (score 3):

To get number of threads of a process, execute

```
grep Threads /proc/<PID>/status
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot execute `/proc/stat`, you can view it, for example with

```
cat /proc/stat
```

`/proc` is a pseudo-filesystem with lots of system information to view. See `man proc` for details. You can read details about linux `/proc/stat` for example at [this page](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can display threads with ps command as well:

```
THREAD DISPLAY
        H     Show threads as if they were processes.
       -L     Show threads, possibly with LWP and NLWP columns.
        m     Show threads after processes.
       -m     Show threads after processes.
       -T     Show threads, possibly with SPID column.
```

For example:

```
ps -T -p $pid
```

to display threads with SPID number of process with PID $pid.